# How to add two background images in css

Tags: html, css

i want help to add two image one over the other and position two images in center

```
<div class="im1"> </div>
.im1{
    position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;
    background-image:url("../images/img-shadow.png"),url("../images/img-1.png");
    background-size:contain;
    height:358px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat;
}
```

background image is with shadow
i want it to be
[image]

Comment: try `background-position: center bottom, left top;` for centering.

Answer (score 1):

This actually can be solved only with CSS.

I created an example here that generates the rotated border of the image.

Now you can insert any image inside :)

p.s of course you need to change the width and the height of the image inside to be the same as the frame diagonal. you can use CSS calculate for this.

```css
body {
  background-color: #F3F5F6;
  }

.shadow:before,
.shadow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 10%;
  max-width: 90%;
  width: 90%;
}

.shadow:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(86deg);
  left: -72px;
  right: auto;
  top: 118px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.shadow:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(84deg);
  left: auto;
  right: -92px;
  bottom: 75px;
  box-shadow: 0 -15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

.pic-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pic {
  background-image: url('http://modernschoolec.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/11-980x408.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  /* (side)(sqrt(2)) */
  width: 282px;
  height: 282px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  left: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box shadow rotate">
  <div class="pic-wrapper">
    <div class="pic"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either give the shadow image a `z-index` of 100 and give the school image a `z-index` of 101 or set one to be `position relative` and one to be `position absolute`, but you will need media queries to make it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

```
.im1{
    background-image:url("../images/img-1.png"),url("../images/img-shadow.png");
    height:358px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat;
   background-position: center , center;
}
```